# Adding lists by element in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I'd like to take a RDD of integer lists and reduce it down to one list.  For example...

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

to

```
[3, 5, 7, 9]
```

I can do this in python using the zip function but not sure how to replicate it in spark besides doing collect on the object but I want to keep the data in the rdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all elements in `rdd` are of the same length, you can use `reduce` with `zip`:

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]])

rdd.reduce(lambda x, y: [i+j for i, j in zip(x, y)])
# [3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: thanks!  I had tried something like that but didn't think of splitting it as x and y.